# Proxy for Tomcat outgoing HTTP requests

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy

I have a JavaEE web application deployed in an Apache Tomcat 7.0.6 under Windows 7 which comunicates with a remote web service to request some data. I would like to intercept the comunication between them with an HTTP proxy, like BurpSuite (http://www.portswigger.net/burp/), so I can see the HTTP messages sent and received by the JavaEE application deployed in Tomcat. Already tried to set my BurpSuite (listening on port 8090/TCP) as a proxy system in Windows 7 and specifying some options for JVM when runs Tomcat (-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.2.16 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8091 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.0.2.16 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8091).

I've been looking for a way to do this but I didn't find anything usefull. Could you please give me hand?

Greetings and thanks in advance.